# Prompt for default activity without actually opening activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to set the default app for a specific mime type. I know how to clear the default but I need to then prompt the user without actually opening the app.

```
PackageManager p = mContext.getPackageManager();
ComponentName cN = new ComponentName(mContext, FakeDownloadActivity.class);
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(cN, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

Intent selector = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT);
selector.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
selector.setType(mimeType);
mContext.startActivity(selector);

p.setComponentEnabledSetting(cN, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

The code above launches the activity rather than ONLY selecting the default activity. It works be enabling a fake activity then disabling it. This causes the Select Default App dialog to show the next time it is called. I simply want to ONLY select the default activity.

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is an `ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY` intent.

First, you create an intent that defines the apps that should be eligible to choose, for instance:

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
```

Then, you create the  `ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY` intent, and as an Extra, you pass the main intent you created before

```
Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY);
pickIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, mainIntent);
```

Now, you just start an activity for result with this intent:

```
startActivityForResult(pickIntent, 0);
```

And a dialog will be created where the used can pick an application, but when clicked, the activity is not launched, instead, it will stay in your activity, and the function `onActivityResult` will be called with the results. So you need to create that function:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

               //In data, you have all the information about the selected application
       if (data != null) {
                 //You can launch the application that we just picked with startActivity(data);
                 //or explore the variable to get all the information than you want
       }
    }
```

Take a look at the `Intent` class. There you have information about the package name, and the class that would be launched.

From now, what you need is to set that package and class as the default to the intent, or whatever else you need. The bad side, is that you only can save that information for your own internal purposes, for example to decide what app to launch next time that the users performs some action. What you cannot do is to modify the system settings to set a default activity for a given intent. Actually, [the package manager has the addPreferredActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#addPreferredActivity%28android.content.IntentFilter,%20int,%20android.content.ComponentName%5B%5D,%20android.content.ComponentName%29) method, that was supposed to do this, but it is deprecated since API level 8, giving this reasons:

> This is a protected API that should not have been available to third
>   party applications. It is the platform's responsibility for assigning
>   preferred activities and this cannot be directly modified. Add a new
>   preferred activity mapping to the system. This will be used to
>   automatically select the given activity component when
>   Context.startActivity() finds multiple matching activities and also
>   matches the given filter.

Comment: Quote: `The bad side, is that you only can save that information for your own internal purposes, for example to decide what app to launch next time that the users performs some action.` - Which is exactly what I am trying to avoid. The solution needs to set Android's system settings for the given Intent.

Comment: I guess you wont be able to do that without opening the app, since as i said, the function for doing that was deprecated in Froyo, because Android team decided that an app shouldent change that and has to be done by means of the default picker created and launcher by the system. At least with this you have a dialog where the user choses an app and you can know which one was selected. It is the best i can come up with. Im afraid i can't do anything else.

Comment: That's what I suspected but I appreciate the effort.